# How to add checkbox and radio button in Profile Page

Tags: customization, profiles, radio

I liked to customize my profile page by adding new fields to get more info from the user like "Gender" or "Speaking Languages". I managed to get the text input form to work, the problem I having now is on the radio and checkbox type of input. 
Here is my code:

```
function my_user_field( $user ) {
            ?>
                <h3><?php _e('More About You'); ?></h3>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="Dealing Type"><?php _e('Gender'); ?>
                        </label></th>
                        <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Gender?'); ?></span><br>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="dealing" value="Male">Male<br /></label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="dealing" value="Female">Female<br /></label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="company"><?php _e('Company'); ?>
                        </label></th>
                        <td>
                          <span class="description"><?php _e('Insert Your Company name'); ?></span><br>
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="language"><?php _e('Language'); ?>
                        </label></th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Engilsh" value="Malay" /> English<br />
                            <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="Mandarin" /> Mandarin<br />


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            <?php }


            function my_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
                    return FALSE;
                update_usermeta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
                update_usermeta( $user_id, 'company', $_POST['company'] );
                update_usermeta( $user_id, 'language', $_POST['language'] );

            }
            add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
            add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

The "Gender" and "Languages" are not passing through the $_post[]. I am new to coding, hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the "checked" value for the inputs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="language" <?php if (get_the_author_meta( 'language', $user->ID) == 'Mandarin' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="Mandarin" /> Mandarin<br />
```

Also, the usermeta is *dealing* but your are checking for `$_POST['gender']`

Finally, you should have one usermeta for English and other for Mandarin, as they are not mutually exlcusive

[edit: working code]
[edit2: multiple languages]

```
<?php
$lingo = array('en' => 'English', 'md' => '普通話', 'es' => 'Español', 'fr' => 'Français', 'pt' => 'Português');

function my_user_field( $user ) {
    $gender = get_the_author_meta( 'dealing', $user->ID);
    $company = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) );
?>
    <h3><?php _e('More About You'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="Dealing Type"><?php _e('Gender'); ?>
            </label></th>
            <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Gender?'); ?></span><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="dealing" <?php if ($gender == 'Male' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="Male">Male<br /></label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="dealing" <?php if ($gender == 'Female' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="Female">Female<br /></label>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="company"><?php _e('Company'); ?>
            </label></th>
            <td>
              <span class="description"><?php _e('Insert Your Company name'); ?></span><br>
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <?php _e('Language'); ?>
            </th>
            <td><?php
                global $lingo;
                foreach($lingo as $key => $value) {
                    $code = 'language_'.$key;
                    $lang = get_the_author_meta( $code, $user->ID);
                     ?>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $code; ?>" <?php if ($lang == 'yes' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="yes" /> <?php echo $value; ?></label><br />
                <?php }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php 
}


function my_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'dealing', $_POST['dealing'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'company', $_POST['company'] );

    global $lingo;
    foreach($lingo as $key => $value) {
        $code = "language_".$key;
        update_usermeta( $user_id, $code, $_POST[$code] );
    }
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_user_field' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I can see how it works, however as for the checkbox type, is that possible to use one usermeta for languages to store both English and Mandarin?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so... Anyway, why would you want that?

Comment: Because I might have plenty of languages to be checked, for the simplification sake, it is better to make it simple in coding. I wondering using array would be possible?

Comment: Updated the code to support any number of languages

Comment: Thanks brasofilo, you are rock!! But how about display the checked item in the front page?

Comment: Nice, thanks! For the frontend, adapt [this function](http://pastebin.com/mMeTXyGR) to your needs

Comment: ok,one last thing. How to insert this table before the password area? For now, this table is only displayed under the Password table, which is quite odd to see. Any hook to this? I tried to looking at it, but couldn't found the appropriate hook for it.

Comment: no, i think this is not possible... the action occurs after the password is printed... maybe jQuery manipulating the DOM... but that deserves another question, and SE is warning me to _avoid extended discussions in comments_ and if I'd like to _automatically move this discussion to chat?_ :o)

Comment: oh...sorry for that, my reputation is not enough to chat... never mind...I try to figure it out myself..anyway...thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is supposed to be in the functions.php file? true/false?

Comment: @Aleks : Have you tried? I don't know how much, but I think most of the code you find here in WPSE is dropped in this file (unless you make a [custom plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users) to deal with this, which is recommended).