# how to add radio field on user meta on function.php?

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, profiles

i have added gender filed on user meta it is not value

```
<?php

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 10 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 10 );

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
                          <section>
                            <label class="label" for="gender">Gender</label>
                            <div class="inline-group">
                                <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline"  <?php if ($gender == 'Male' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="Male"><i></i>Male</label>
                                <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline"  <?php if ($gender == 'Female' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> value="Female"><i></i>Female</label>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <!-- sex -->
 <?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
?>
```

i saw this same question but still not saving
[How to add checkbox and radio button in Profile Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49748/how-to-add-checkbox-and-radio-button-in-profile-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong name on the radio inputs, `radio-inline` but when you try to get that value you are using `$_POST['gender']`

I've updated you code and made some improvement too, with the `checked()` function

```
function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 

    $gender = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'gender', true );
?>

<section>
    <label class="label" for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="inline-group">
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="gender"  <?php  checked( $gender, 'Male' ); ?> value="Male" /> <i>Male</i></label>
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="gender"  <?php  checked( $gender, 'Female' ); ?> value="Female" /> <i>Female</i></label>
    </div>
</section>

 <?php }
```

OBS: you should sanitize data too.

OBS2: Do what @kaiser said:

> Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Sorry for bad english